# Download a zip file using curl or wget

Tags: php, curl, cookies, download, wget

I need to download several zip files from this web page ....

http://www.geoportale.regione.lombardia.it/download-pacchetti?p_p_id=dwnpackageportlet_WAR_geoportaledownloadportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&metadataid=%7B16C07895-B75B-466A-B980-940ECA207F64%7D

using curl or wget, so not in interactive way,

A sample url is the follow ...

http://www.geoportale.regione.lombardia.it/rlregis_download/service/package?dbId=323&cod=12

If I use this link in a new browser tab or window, all works fine but using curl or wget it's not possible to download the zipfile.

Trying to see what happen in the browser using Firebug, or in general the browser console, I can see that there is first a POST request and then a GET request (using Firebug ... ), so I'm not able to reproduce these requests using curl or wget.

Could be also that some cookies are sets in the browser session and the links do not work without that cookie?

Any suggestion will be appreciated ....

Cesare

NOTE: when I try to use a wget this is my result

[image]

NOTE 2: 404 Not found

[image]

NOTE 3 (the solution): the right command is

```
wget "http://www.geoportale.regione.lombardia.it/rlregis_download/service/package?dbId=323&cod=12"
```

then I've to rename the file in something like "pippo.zip" and this is my result, or, better using the -O option in this manner

```
wget "http://www.geoportale.regione.lombardia.it/rlregis_download/service/package?dbId=323&cod=12" -O pippo.zip
```

Comment: How about using a tool like selenium?

Comment: I shoud like to use something simpler than Selenium .... anyway, do you have a sample using selenium?

Comment: I just tried wget and it worked for me... What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: Really? I've added a note in my original text with a picture of my cygwin session .... If you try to see the content of the file you'll see that there is a an error ..... Thank you!

Comment: You're missing the quotes on the URL? Use `wget "http://www.geoportale.regione.lombardia.it/rlregis_download/service/package?dbId=323&cod=12"`

Comment: uhmmm ... 404 Not Found ... see NOTE 2 ... :-(

Comment: you're adding some extra characters... Try again the same url as before, but type it yourself, without copy-pasting it please.

Comment: I'm sorry ... nothing change ...

Comment: Look at the output of wget. It's trying to connect to that URL, but there's some extra characters after `rlregis_download`. There's extra characters being copied when directly copy-pasting from StackOverflow. So just type it yourself and show me the output please.

Comment: You're right!!! The command is wget "http://www.geoportale.regione.lombardia.it/rlregis_download/service/package?dbId=323&cod=12" and now it's working. Please answer to my request (not only in comment ... ) so I can vote you and your solution. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Done! No problem, happy it helped

Comment: You don't need to rename the file afterwards: you can do `wget "XXX" -O pippo.zip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your command, you're missing the double quotes. Your command should be:

`wget "http://www.geoportale.regione.lombardia.it/rlregis_download‌​/service/package?dbI‌​d=323&cod=12"`

That should download it properly.